# Не получается сменить время файла

Tags: winapi, ассемблер

Программа должна выводить все файлы в заданной папке и две кнопки к ним: "ОК" и "Отмена". При нажатии "ОК" время файла должно менятся на заданное мной (в данном случае я беру его с GetLocalTime. Все работает, кроме, собственно, смены времени. Подозреваю, что проблема где-то между строчками "jz next" и "next:", 
Код:
Asm файл:

```
.386
.model flat,STDCALL

include Lab2.inc
.code

Begin:
call main
invoke ExitProcess,NULL
main proc

    invoke FindFirstFile, addr findPattern, addr fileStruct
    cmp eax, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    je exit
    mov hFind, eax
l1:
    cmp fileStruct.cFileName, '.'
    je next
    invoke MessageBox,0, addr fileStruct.cFileName, 0, MB_OKCANCEL
    cmp eax, IDCANCEL
    jz next
    invoke GetLocalTime, addr newTime
    invoke CreateFile, addr fileStruct.cFileName, GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0
    mov hFile, eax
    invoke SetFileTime, hFile, addr newTime, addr newTime, addr newTime
    invoke CloseHandle, hFile
next:
    invoke FindNextFile, hFind, addr fileStruct
    cmp eax, 0
    jnz l1
    invoke FindClose, hFind

exit:
    ret
main endp
end Begin
```

Inc файл:

```
include WINDOWS.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc
includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data

findPattern db 'd:/Lab2/*.*', 0 
hFind dd 0
fileStruct WIN32_FIND_DATA <0>
hFile dd 0
newTime SYSTEMTIME <0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`GetLocalTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlocaltime) возвращает данные в структуре [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime), а [`SetFileTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime) должна получать на вход структуры [`FILETIME`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime). Разница между этими структурами очевидна:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME, *LPSYSTEMTIME;

typedef struct _FILETIME {
  DWORD dwLowDateTime;
  DWORD dwHighDateTime;
} FILETIME, *PFILETIME, *LPFILETIME;
```

В вашем коде вы используете одну и ту же структуру `SYSTEMTIME`.

Для конвертации данных между этими структурами нужно использовать функцию [`SystemTimeToFileTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetofiletime), как показано в примере на Си ниже ([**источник**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/sysinfo/changing-a-file-time-to-the-current-time)):

```
#include <windows.h>

// SetFileToCurrentTime - sets last write time to current system time
// Return value - TRUE if successful, FALSE otherwise
// hFile  - must be a valid file handle

BOOL SetFileToCurrentTime(HANDLE hFile)
{
    FILETIME ft;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    BOOL f;

    GetSystemTime(&st);              // Gets the current system time
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);  // Converts the current system time to file time format
    f = SetFileTime(hFile,           // Sets last-write time of the file 
        (LPFILETIME) NULL,           // to the converted current system time 
        (LPFILETIME) NULL, 
        &ft);    

    return f;
}
```